# How do I save an image to disk using NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

How do I save an image to disk (image coming from a link) using NestJS.

The image comes after the user search. Stay in doc.avatar

My Controller:

```
  @Get('user/:id/avatar')
  async setAvatar(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const userData = this.apiService.getUser(id);    
    return this.apiService.avatar(await userData);
  }
```

My Service:

```
  async avatar(doc) {

    if(doc !== '') {
      @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor(doc.avatar, {
          dest: '../../files/'
        }),
      )
      uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
          console.log(file);
          return file;
      }
    }
      return await new this.imageModel({
        userId: doc.id,
        hash: doc.avatar
      }).save();
  }
```

I tried to do it in the service and directly in the controller, but I always get an error, or it just doesn't work

My structure

[My structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPpPx.jpg)

Comment: can you provide your error?

Comment: He doesn't give an error. Nothing just happens. The bank saves the image link correctly, but the image on disk does not save

Comment: can you show your `MulterModule.registerAsync` config in module file

Comment: I added a photo of my structure